# Insert date string into array of ordered date strings at correct index

Tags: ios, arrays, xcode, swift, date

I have an array of dates that are in the form of strings, and I want to organize them by the oldest dates last. The circumstances are I have a list of dates(already organized), and I am inserting a date. For instance, I want to insert `"08/23/2015"` in

`["08/27/2015", "08/27/2015", "08/25/2015", "08/21/2015"]`

So it appears at index 3.

I tried:

```
        var id = -1
        var index = datesArray.dates.count
        let newDate = "08/23/2015"

        let dDateStr = stringFromDate("08/23/2015")
        let cDateStr = stringFromDate(NSDate())

        if dDateStr != cDateStr {
            while id < 0 && index > 0 {
                if dateFromString(dDateStr).timeIntervalSinceNow >= dateFromString(destView.dates[index]).timeIntervalSinceNow  {
                    id = index
                }
                index = index - 1
            }
            id = 0
        }
        else {
            id = 0
        }
        datesArray.insert(newDate, atIndex: id)
```

Yet, it always gives me `id = -1`. Any advice?

I am using Swift 1.2 on Xcode 6.4 for iOS 8

Comment: By the way, if you use standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) formats `YYYY-MM-DD` and `YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS.SSSZ` then alphabetical sorting of text is also chronological.

Comment: Was there a reason why you didn't simply append the new date and then sort it again? It seems silly, but iOS has a `sortedArrayUsing` family of mehtods on arrays and unless you do some specific low level optimizations I'd say they are a safe bet to be most(ish) performant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I changed your code quite a bit but it works now (changed because I partially did not understand what your code was supposed to do exactly.):

```
func dateFromString (string:String) -> NSDate {
    let df = NSDateFormatter()
    df.dateFormat = "MM/dd/yyyy"
    return df.dateFromString(string)!
}

var datesArray = ["08/27/2015", "08/27/2015", "08/25/2015", "08/21/2015"]
var id = 0
var index = datesArray.count
let newDateString = "08/23/2015"
let newDate = dateFromString(newDateString).timeIntervalSinceNow

for index in 0..<datesArray.count {
    if dateFromString(datesArray[index]).timeIntervalSinceNow >= newDate {
        id = index + 1
    }
}

datesArray.insert(newDateString, atIndex: id)
```

Please note that it still is not the most performant code possible.

But it outputs

> 3

and can insert at the first and last position as well.

You may have to change the array reference and stuff like that because I do not know in what way you are planning to include this snippet.

Comment: Thank you so much, it worked like a charm. Sorry about not giving enough information, I'll try to make it more clear